# Python Date Format from YYYYMMDD to YYMMDD

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, python-datetime, python-dateutil

The current code pulls the date as YYYYMMDD. Is there a way to change the following to a YYMMDD format, with YY being the last two digits of the year? So in this case, 21? IE, 210324. Thanks in advance.

```
folder_path = r'\\FolderA\FolderB\File_{}.csv'.format(date_dict['date_time'].strftime("%y%m%d"))
```

Comment: That looks like it should do it, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), `%y` is the code for the last two digits of a year

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
folder_path = r'\\FolderA\FolderB\File_{}.csv'.format(datetime.strptime(date_dict['date_time'], "%Y%m%d").strftime("%y%m%d"))
```

Comment: Is pandas necessary here? Could be done with the standard datetime module

Comment: Indeed, I was under the false impression that pandas was being used here. I updated my answer to do without it.